# How to make custom scrollbar jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I was thinking to make custom scrollbar jQuery plugin, there are many plugins available for it but I want to make my own, problem is I am not getting the concept that how should I move a content by moving other div element (scrollbar) and also how should I move content by using mouse scroller??

Please help me to understand this.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't tried any available plugin, I just want to make my own so before starting, idea should be clear that what's the concept/logic behind it, if its clear then I can start to build one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

## Scrollbars logic

```
(onInit, onResize) thumbSize = viewportSize * viewportSize / areaSize
(onThumbDrag)      viewportScrollPos = areaSize / viewportSize * thumbPos
(onViewportScroll) thumbPos = viewportScrollPos / viewportSize * thumbSize
```

The easiest concept would be to use the jQuery UI draggable and attach the `.draggable()` Method to the `.scrollbar`

```js
var $scrollable  = $(".scrollable"),
    $scrollbar   = $(".scrollbar"),
    height       = $scrollable.outerHeight(true),    // visible height
    scrollHeight = $scrollable.prop("scrollHeight"), // total height
    barHeight    = height * height / scrollHeight;   // Scrollbar height!

// Scrollbar drag:
$scrollbar.height( barHeight ).draggable({
  axis : "y",
  containment : "parent", 
  drag: function(e, ui) {
    $scrollable.scrollTop( scrollHeight / height * ui.position.top  );
  }
}); 

// Element scroll:
$scrollable.on("scroll", function() {
  $scrollbar.css({top: $scrollable.scrollTop() / height * barHeight });
});
```

```css
.parent{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:200px;
  width:180px;
  background:#ddd;
}
.scrollable{
  overflow-y:scroll;
  position:absolute;
  padding:0 17px 0 0;
  width: 180px;
  height:100%;
}
.scrollbar{
  cursor:n-resize;
  position:absolute;
  overflow:auto;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  z-index:2;
  background:#444;
  width:17px;
  border-radius:8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="scrollbar"></div>
  <div class="scrollable">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.       
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.
  </div>
</div>
```

The above is just an example with the needed logic and math involved,
it misses the "hide-scrollbar", just to keep it simple. I'll leave to you to add all the needed tweaks, addons.

Comment: this is g8, really g8 and soon you will see the plugin, need to apply many more things into this, but I will try to do that..
Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Dheeraj can't wait to see your script! Good luck!

Comment: Hi roXon, how can I make this work by scrolling with mouse-wheel?

Answer (score -1):

Make custom scrollbar **without jQuery-UI** .

**HTML:-**

```
    <div class="parent">
            <div class="scrollbar"></div>
            <div class="scrollable">
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                 consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras non nunc eget sapien molestie mollis. 
                 Proin vestibulum vehicula varius. Duis a nunc ac risus facilisis consectetur.</p> 
           </div>
   </div>
```

**css:-**

```
.parent{
    position:relative;
       margin:50px;
      overflow:hidden;
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background:#ddd;
}
.scrollable{
      overflow-y:scroll;
    position:absolute;
      padding:0 17px 0 0;
    width: 180px;
      height:100%;
}
.scrollbar{

    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:7px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

**Javascript:-**

```
  var $scrollable = $('.scrollable');
  var $scrollbar  = $('.scrollbar');
  $scrollable.outerHeight(true);
  var H   = $scrollable.outerHeight(true);
  var sH  = $scrollable[0].scrollHeight;
  var  sbH = H*H/sH;



$('.scrollbar').height(sbH);

$scrollable.on("scroll", function(){

    $scrollbar.css({top: $scrollable.scrollTop()/H*sbH });
});
```